# What is "Sticky to top of lists" value?

Tags: views, 8

I'm creating a view, and I've pulled in the *sticky to top of lists* field, as well as a view conditional field. I want to determine if "sticky" is true, and set a value (so I can add it to a custom field as a css class, for styling purposes) i.e., "stickyitem" if true, nothing/null if false.

I can't seem to get that in the conditional field. I've tried:

- Not empty, which makes it show everywhere
- Equal to 1, which seems like the correct choice, but it doesn't work
- Equal to true
- Equal to yes

What else could it possibly be? Maybe using *equal to* is the wrong choice.

Answer (score 1):

oh dear lord.. Didn't dawn on me to make the field visible so I could see it.

The answer is "on"